# Detox .tap() function only highlights, does not press. Why?

Tags: android, react-native, detox

I am testing a react-native app on Android, which uses buttons from native `Pressable` class*. This all works in layout inspector, and Detox is able to find the button as visible.

However when I try to `await element(by.id('button')).tap()`, the button only gets highlighted, and not pressed properly. Same if I use `.multiTap(10)` instead, and same if I wait a few seconds before.

`element.longPress()` (and manual tap) works, but is painfully slow on Android.

Did this happen to you before? How do I address this?

Using Detox v20 and react-native v0.70

*Same happens for `TouchableOpacity` or `TouchableHighlight`, which will perform the opacity/highlight effect, but not follow through with `onClick` function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this might be a bug on Android API 33 (doesn't happen elsewhere). I opened an [issue](https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues/3879).